# Solve for x: $4\log_{x/2}(\sqrt{x}) + 2 \log_{4x} (x^2) = 3 \log_{2x} (x^3)$

Tags: logarithms

$$4\log_{x/2}(\sqrt{x}) + 2 \log_{4x} (x^2)  = 3 \log_{2x} (x^3)$$

This is a different type of equation. Our school has not taught this type yet. But this came in our exams. Can someone please help? 
I don't understand the bases are all different. How can I proceed? 
Please I need a step wise solution. Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean $2\log_{4x}(x^2)$ by `2 log(x^2) base(4x)`? I don't even know if it's a allowed to have a non-constant variable as the base, but you may be able to use $\log_b(a) = \frac{\ln(a)}{\ln(b)}$.

Comment: "the bases are all different": then convert to a common base.

Answer (score 4):

Let me see if I guessed correctly what you wrote:

$$4\log_{x/2}\sqrt x+2\log_{4x}x^2=3\log_{2x}x^3\iff2\log_{x/2}x+4\log_{4x}x=9\log_{2x}x\implies$$

$$2\frac{\log x}{\log\frac x2}+4\frac{\log x}{\log 4x}=9\frac{\log x}{\log 2x}$$

where $\;log\;$ above can be *at any base you want* (though in higher mathematics it is usually taken to be $\;\log_e\;$)

Now you could assume $\;x\neq 1\;$ (otherwise the exercise is very boring) and thus *divide* through the whole last equation by $\;\log x\;$ , and then use other properties of logarithms, say like $\;\log AB=\log A+\log B\;$ , or $\;\log\frac AB=\log A-\log B\;$ , etc.

Also make sure you understand and can justify the first steps shown above.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. I can understand upto the 3rd step. Now should I approach by taking the formula logA/B?

Comment: @Ritwika If you mean the jump from the first to the second line of equations is hard: use what Maximilian proposes in his comment: change of base in logarithms. That is what I used there...

Comment: Actually I am not being to change the base after your 3rd step. Can you please help me?

Comment: @Ritwika Do you mean, for example, that $\;4\log_{x/2}\sqrt x=2\log_{x/2}x\;$ ? That only uses the property $\;\log x^n=n\log x\;$ and also the trivial $\;\sqrt x=x^{1/2}\;$ .

Comment: The base is already changed, it's the $\log_{x/2}(\sqrt{x}) = \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\ln(x/2)}$ step. Then $\sqrt{x} = x^{1/2}$ and $\ln(a^b) = b\ln(a)$. Also other hint: $\log(x/2) = \log(x) - \log(2)$, also $\log(4x) = \log(x) + \log(4)$, you will be able to reduce everything to $\log(x) + \text{something}$. Also be caerful when dividing by $\ln(x)$, make sure $\ln(x) \neq 0$ and check that seperate case in case it it.

Comment: @Joanpemo Should I have to divide the last equation by **log(x)**  on both left hand side and right hand side?

Comment: @Ritwika Whatever you do (mathematically sound, of course) with one side of an equality you *must* do exactly the same on the side...always. I think that dividing by $\;\log x\neq0\iff x\neq1\;$ in the last equality can help to make things a little simpler.

Comment: I have solved this equation! But I am new to stackexchange so I don't know how to give codes so that I can post the answer. :(

Comment: Basically, I just changed your third equation a bit. I wrote, 2/ (log X/2 base x) + 4/ (log 4x base x) =9 /(log 2xbasex). As the bases are all x , I assumed log 2 base x=a and completed it.